# syslog.h increase the number of LOG_LOCAL

Tags: syslog

I have the need for multiple logs (up to 12) and ideally they need to be in their own file. The below in syslog.h is not going to be enough.

```
#define LOG_LOCAL0      (16<<3) /* reserved for local use */
#define LOG_LOCAL1      (17<<3) /* reserved for local use */
#define LOG_LOCAL2      (18<<3) /* reserved for local use */
#define LOG_LOCAL3      (19<<3) /* reserved for local use */
#define LOG_LOCAL4      (20<<3) /* reserved for local use */
#define LOG_LOCAL5      (21<<3) /* reserved for local use */
#define LOG_LOCAL6      (22<<3) /* reserved for local use */
#define LOG_LOCAL7      (23<<3) /* reserved for local use */

#define LOG_NFACILITIES 24      /* current number of facilities */
```

Can I add LOG_LOCAL8-12 and increase the LOG_NFACILITIES? Will this work without causing any problems?

Thank you!

CentOS-7.2 / Rocky Linux.